# How to get BitBucket Server v5.15.1 (on-premise) webhook to trigger Lambda via API Gateway to get into S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, bitbucket-server

I'm working with an on-premise older version of BitBucket Server v5.15.1 that does not have the Bitbucket Pipelines feature and I need how to get the webhooks to notify AWS Lambda via HTTPS POST via AWS API Gateway after a commit is made to master branch...then Lambda downloads a copy of the repo, zips it up and places it into an S3 bucket...and of course this is where CodePipeline can finally be triggered...But I'm having issues getting this on-premise BitBucket Server located within my AWS account to connect its webhook to Lambda.

I tried following this documentation below and launched the CloudFormation template with all the needed resources but I'm assuming it is for BitBucket Cloud not Bitbucket Server OP.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/integrating-git-with-aws-codepipeline/

Anyones help with this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are following this below blog from AWS :
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/integrating-codepipeline-with-on-premises-bitbucket-server/

We had also implemented it. If the event is coming to Lambda, then make sure your Lambda is within a VPC and it has correct outbound(read as inbound) rules to connect the Bitbucket server over HTTPS. Also the Bitbucket server accepts the VPC IP range.